# Android Camera App using CameraX to save images in YUV_420_888 format

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camerax

I want to save image stream (preferably 30fps) to the device. I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522701/android-camera2-jpeg-framerate).

How do I dump images in `YUV_420_888` format using `cameraX` without encoding it in `JPEG`?

Also, I'll be glad if any one can suggest any direction in saving burst of images.

Till now I'm only saving an image by `onclick` of button

```
findViewById(R.id.capture_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "Image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        imageCapture.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                Toast.makeText(CameraCaptureActivity.this, "Photo saved as " + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError imageCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                Toast.makeText(CameraCaptureActivity.this, "Couldn't save photo: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (cause != null)
                    cause.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "save image stream" and "burst of images"(How large is the number of images?)., And what problem you are having in current approach? (Can't dump in YUV_420_888 format? or only one image is saved?)

Comment: @samabcde With 'saving image stream' I mean mainly to save images at 30fps on the disk. Currently, I'm only saving an image at a time to the disk,

Comment: Could you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I dump images in YUV_420_888 format using cameraX without
>   encoding it as JPEG?

You can use another version of `ImageCapture.takePicture()` that returns an im-memory image in YUV_420_888 format, [`ImageCapture.takePicture(Executor, OnImageCaptureCallback)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#takePicture(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback)).

```java
imageCapture.takePicture(executor, new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {

   @Override
   public void onCaptureSuccess (ImageProxy imageProxy) {
      // Use the image, then make sure to close it before returning from the method
      imageProxy.close()
   }

   @Override
   public void onError (ImageCaptureException exception) {
      // Handle the exception however you'd like
   }
})
```

> I'll be glad I could any direction in saving burst of images.

Burst images are images taken one after another at a certain rate. How you implement it in your app depends on what you want the user experience to look like, it can be triggered from a single button click or a long click. The main thing is you'll have to make a number of calls to `ImageCapture.takePicture()`, you can control the image capture rate using APIs such as [`Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, Long)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)).

Comment: In onCaptureSuccess method How do I save the image to the disk? Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984622/how-to-save-a-yuv-420-888-image way right to do that?

Comment: The imageProxy object here is a JPEG and not YUV_420_888 (as with the ImageAnalysis) use case. I'm running an inline debugger inside the onCaptureSuccess and 'image.format' returns '256' rather than '35'. The reason I found this was that I can no longer use the [YuvToRgbConverter=(https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/3730442b49189f76a1083a98f3acf3f5f09222a3/CameraUtils/lib/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera/utils/YuvToRgbConverter.kt) as it asserts the YUV_420_888 in the `imageToByteBuffer()` method

Comment: I'm not seeing any builder functionality to set the image format either.